# Is there a simpler way to change a single array value?

Tags: php, arrays, post, if-statement, foreach

What I'm trying to do is default the `$names` array value to it's parallel `$urls` value if a `$_POST[]` value of `$names` is empty. (This is based on the assumption that an empty `$_POST[]` will return empty, someone please correct me if I'm wrong).

Here's my code:

```
$urls = array(1 => $_POST['url_1'], 2 => ['url_2'], 3 => $_POST['url_3'], 4 => $_POST['url_4'], 5 => $_POST['url_5']);
$names = array(1 => $_POST['name_1'], 2 => ['name_2'], 3 => $_POST['name_3'], 4 => $_POST['name_4'], 5 => $_POST['name_5']);

if(empty($names[1])) { $names[1] = $_POST['url_1']; }
if(empty($names[2])) { $names[2] = $_POST['url_2']; }
if(empty($names[3])) { $names[3] = $_POST['url_3']; }
if(empty($names[4])) { $names[4] = $_POST['url_4']; }
if(empty($names[5])) { $names[5] = $_POST['url_5']; }
```

I thought about using a `foreach()` loop, but I don't really see how that would work, as each individual array value e.g. `$names[1]` would have to be set to `$urls[1]` if empty.

Any advice, comments or other information would be very much appreciated :)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $names[$i] = !empty($_POST['name_' . $i]) ? $_POST['name_' . $i] : $_POST['url_' . $i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan :). Does `!empty($_POST['name_' . $i]) ? $_POST['name_' . $i] : $_POST['url_' . $i];` act as as `if()` in and of it self, and if so, do you mind telling me what "it's" (not sure how to term it) called?

Comment: It's called the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). Yes it's equivalent to `if (!empty($_POST['name_' . $i]) $names[$i] = $_POST['name_' . $i]; else $names[$i] = $_POST['url_' . $i];`

Comment: So with this, I should strip out `$names = array()` right, as this defines the array values for both empty and non-empty cases? Sorry for the ignorance of my question :), just want to make sure I understand 100%.

Comment: This code does not rely on any arrays other than `$_POST` already existing, correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    if (empty($names[$i])) {
        $names[$i] = $_POST['url_' . $i];
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that you also need to check if `$_POST['url_' . $i']` exists too with additional `isset()` check

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :). In this case, should I do something like `for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
if(isset($_POST['url_' . $i])) { continue; } else { break;}
$names[$i] = $_POST['url_' . $i];
    if (empty($names[$i])) {
        $names[$i] = $_POST['url_' . $i];
    }
}` which would also set the `$names = array()` values? Also, is there any reason why whitespace should be left in `['url_' . $i]`?

Comment: @Pixelatron: `if (empty($names[$i]) && isset($_POST['url_' . $i])) {` is better imho. Spaces are placed there to make the code more readable

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($names as $k=>$v){
if(empty($v)){
 $names[$k] =$urls[$k];
// or  $names[$k] = $_POST['url_' . $k'];
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input :). I see you went with what I originally said about `foreach()`, which is nice to see, but I just read an article on PHP benchmark resource usage and it seems that `foreach()` is considerably slower than `for()` so I've accepted an answers using `for()` as it seems appropriate to get into a habit of using the most efficient function. Thanks though :).

Comment: i prefer foreach, for the power of $k=>$v, not all arrays will have keys in a sequential numeric range.

Answer (score 0):

```
$urls = array(1 => $_POST['url_1'], $_POST['url_2'], $_POST['url_3'], $_POST['url_4'], $_POST['url_5']);
$names = array(1 => $_POST['name_1'], $_POST['name_2'], $_POST['name_3'], $_POST['name_4'], $_POST['name_5']);

for ( $c = 1; $c <= 5; $c++ )
{
  if(empty($names[$c])) 
  { 
    $postKey = 'url_'.$c;
    $names[$c] = $_POST[$postKey]; 
  }
}
```